# Descobrir sequencia numerica em array javascript

Tags: javascript

Olá!

dado o seguinte array:

```
let array = [3,6,9,10,11,12,16,19]
```

Preciso pegar os valores sequenciais desse array ou seja, somente os numeros 9 10 11 12 e guardar em outro array. como faria isso?

obrigado!

Comment: Caso a entrada seja `[3, 6, 9, 10, 11, 12, 16, 19, 20, 21, 22]` o que deverá ser retornado?

Comment: Deverá ser retornado todas as sequencias, porem isso que preciso fazer, é em um objeto que contem dia mês e ano que eu uso em um calendário no react native. vamos dizer que a logica seja assim: no meu calendário se estiver marcado 3 6 e 9 ele marca em uma lista os dias com sua descrição. caso seja sequencia ou um range 10 11 12 13 14, preciso saber que tenho uma sequencia que vai de 10 a 14 e adicionar a lista como somente um item que tem a mesma descrição, eu nao preciso criar esses dias pois a descrição deles é a mesma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma alternativa é utilizar uma pilha para armazenar os números sucessivos.
Funciona assim:

- Para cada elementos da entrada olhe para o próximo vizinho:

  - se o elemento for consecutivo o empilhe e olhe para o próximo vizinho repetindo esse passo sucessivamente se necessário.
  - se o elemento não for consecutivo descarregue a pilha dentro do resultado e aponte para o ultimo elemento verificado.

```js
let arr = [3, 6, 9, 10, 11, 12, 16, 19, 20, 21, 22, 25];
let resultado = [];

//Para cada elementos da entrada...
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  let pilha = [arr[i]];                        //inicializa a pilha com o elemento.
  let j = i + 1;                               //Aponta o primeiro candidato a consecutivo.
  //Para cada consecutivo...
  for (; arr[j] == pilha[pilha.length - 1] + 1; j++)
    pilha.push(arr[j]);                        //Empilha o consecutivo.
  if (pilha.length > 1) resultado.push(pilha); //Se a pilha possui mais de um elemento a descarrega no resultado.
  i = j - 1;                                   //Aponta para o ultimo elemento pesquisado.
}


console.log(resultado);
```

No comentário você apresentou outro requisito o de também exibir individualmente números que não formem listas. Para isso basta remover a comparação de tamanho da pilha antes de compor o resultado.

```js
let arr = [3, 6, 9, 10, 11, 12, 16, 19, 20, 21, 22, 25];
let resultado = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  let pilha = [arr[i]];
  let j = i + 1;
  for (; arr[j] == pilha[pilha.length - 1] + 1; j++)
    pilha.push(arr[j]);
  resultado.push(pilha); //Descarrega a pilha no resultado sem fazer comparações de tamanho.
  i = j - 1;
}


console.log(resultado);
```

Answer (score 0):

fiz assim, funciona.

```js
let teste = [3, 6, 9, 10, 11, 12, 16, 19];

filtro = [];
anterior = '';
lock = 0;
for (x = 0; x < teste.length; x++) {
  atual = teste[x];
  if (anterior == '') {
    filtro[filtro.length] = atual;
    anterior = atual;
  } else if (atual == anterior + 1) {
    filtro[filtro.length] = atual;
    lock = 1;
    anterior = atual;
  } else if (lock) {
    break;
  } else {
    filtro = [];
    anterior = '';
  }
}
console.log(filtro);
```